# Show the link to the recent version of a question during an edit from the post edit page for <2000 rep users (not the inline editor for >=2000 rep)

Tags: feature-request, edits

When you edit a question from the [post edit page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/411561/edit) (not the inline editor available to users with > 2k reputation), you might want to have a look again at the original to check some wording - or to find out what the last edit was about. [In order to view the edit page, users with > 2k reputation will need to open the URL to which the "edit" button points, not just click the button; e.g. middle-click to open the URL in a new tab).]

I tried to edit a question with "Improve this question", and the issue it is the same with a normal edit. To find out more about the last edits, I had to open a new tab and search for the same question again. Instead, there should be a link to the original question which you could then open in a new tab if you wish.

If I click on "Title", I only mark the full title, you may check it in an edit page with a rev select box like with the used example [Evaluation of topic modeling: How to understand a coherence value / c_v of 0.4, is it good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54762690/edit).

[image]

Same with a [normal edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/411561/edit) like the edit of this very question:

[image]

Therefore, the feature request is still open, the answer that says that there is a big header at the top is not valid since there is no such header in these two example links given here.

#### Feature request:

Add a button somewhere in the edit window like "Click here to open a new tab with the original question.", for example:

[image]

#### Why:

Here are the screenshots of my edits and one previous rollback to see what was edited in the past. You cannot get there directly since you would lose your edit (or if not - since such text normally gets saved -  you would still be afraid of losing it or would not want to leave the edit page at all).

##### Original:

[image]

##### Planned edit:

[image]

##### Needed check during edit:

In order to find out whether I could also click the checkbox

> This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.

I had to look up the last edits, thus I needed to open a previous edit, but I needed to get this in a new tab by searching for the question again and open it from the search results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The title at the very top of the page is a link to the current version. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3bRn.jpg

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz aaah I see. I did not know. Perhaps it should be made clearer then.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz There was a misunderstanding. There are different editors around for < and > 2000 rep. But the feature-request is about the editor for < 2000 reputation and then, there is no such big title to click on. The question is edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have such a link visible to you (see samcarter's answer), I suggest middle-clicking on your browser's "back" button. In most browsers, this opens the previous page from your history in a new tab, which should be the question you clicked the edit link from.

Comment: Now that is a trick! Never heard of. From now on, it will be in my toolset for the whole web. The average user will not know it, though. Therefore, having a link would make it easier.

Comment: You can also right-click that button, which shows a menu of previously visited pages (basically a preview of what hitting Back many times will do). The same works on the forward button, albeit with similar utility as the forward button ;).

Answer (score 5):

There is already a very big link at the very top of the edit page: the title will take you to the current version of the post:

[image]

Comment: I oversaw "Title" as a link, you only see it of course, when you hover over it and the arrow becomes a hand with a forefinger. I thought it would be just a text header. Therefore it is not that obvious, saying this not after my first edit here. Anyway, now I know, thanks.

Comment: This only applies to the on-page editor. Not to the [edit page itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/411561/edit). The screenshots in the question are of the edit page. (Given they have a "rev" select box.)

Comment: @Ivar Thank you for pointing this out. I edited the question. I misunderstood even this answer since I thought that in the screenshot of this answer, the big title was added by the user to make clear that the "Title" text field left below is the "big link" (and I did not even check this afterwards, believing that clicking on the "Title" text is all I need). Double confusion here since I did not have this title in any of the two edit page checks that I did, I thought it *had* to have been added manually here.