# Show full editor comment when hovering over previous edits in the drop down menu of the edit mode (if the comment is cut-off by the menu border)

Tags: feature-request, edits

I would like to see each comment of the previous edits in its full length when I hover with the mouse over the items of the drop down menu of the edit mode.

Example:

[image]

At the time of the screenshot, the mouse arrow hovers over the first edit comment that was cut off on the right by the drop down menu border.

I would like to see the full comment popping up in a text box in front of the menu point at max at page width (see the example below), or as a prolongation of the menu to the right.

As a comparison: I saw this feature in the Citavi document manager. Cut-off categories in the category tree like:

[image]

are shown in full a text box in front of the category item if you hover over it:

[image]

Comment: "I need to see the full comment of the previous edits" Erm, any reason why?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I made a change to a closed question and I was curious about what the previous edit tried to reopen it again - and what it commented on that. I needed to know whether my changes to improve the question were enough to mark the change as relevant for a reopening, see the example at [Show the link to the recent version of a question during an edit from the post edit page (not the inline editor)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411561/show-the-link-to-the-recent-version-of-a-question-during-an-edit-from-the-post-e).

Comment: Are the edit messages actually helpful for that? I would assume in the vast number of cases one would have to look at the actual edit (title+body diff) anyway.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I agree that you usually do not care so much and just look at the differences (which I did). But in this case, I also wanted to know the reasoning, and that reasoning was cut off.

Comment: Re *"You cannot see the mouse arrow"*: [Freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) (or similar) to the rescue  (seriously).

Comment: My slightly uneducated guess is that this is one simple `title` attribute away, which *does* seem to work on `<select>` + `<option>` elements (at least in Chrome).